# Does Sql Server Compact Edition 3.5 query timeout?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

I just realized that `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` objects timeout properties are readonly with default value set to 0. Does this mean queries to SqlCe database never timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No they do timeout**, you can define the timeout in connection string like this

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False; Data Source = Northwind.sdf;" + 
"Password = <password>; server=mySQLServer;Connect Timeout=30";
```

This is whay [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has to say. ConnectionTimeout Property is the time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to open. The value is always 0 in SQL Server Compact as it is readonly.

Comment: A question that pops up is that if the connection string can be defined with the timeout value then why isn't the `ConnectionTimeout` property set internally with the timeout value from the connection string. Why is it always 0?

Comment: @rageit very valid question, but i guess Eric Lippert can answer that